# How to use runBatch in Database.LevelDB.Higher?

Tags: haskell, leveldb

I'm playing with [Database.LevelDB.Higher](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/higher-leveldb-0.1.0.0/docs/Database-LevelDB-Higher.html) and while the performance is good for occasional get and put, it's not great for building a big database like this:

```
runCreateLevelDB "mydb" "" $
    mapM_ (uncurry put . serialize) bigTable
```

Takes 65s to insert 1M small records. My guess is there's some overhead to each `put` call and that's why the documentation mentions these:

```
runBatch :: MonadLevelDB m => WriterT WriteBatch m () -> m ()
putB :: MonadLevelDB m => Key -> Value -> WriterT WriteBatch m ()
```

The documentation is a bit cryptic and I'm having a hard time understanding the types. This, in particular doesn't work:

```
runCreateLevelDB "mydb" "" $
    runBatch
        mapM (uncurry putB . serialize) bigTable
```

I was surprised to find exactly no codes using `Database.LevelDB.Higher` on GitHub. It seems like a powerful tool.

### Update

I did find an example in the test suite for leveldb-higher itself. I was so close

```
runCreateLevelDB "mydb" "" $ do
    runBatch $
        mapM_ (uncurry putB . serialize) bigTable
```

But still, this takes 59s. So maybe the performance is not so good ...

Comment: You can and should post your answer as an actual answer, not just an update to the question. Note also that the `do` is redundant; all you were missing was the `$` and using `mapM_` instead of `mapM`. Did you try profiling or otherwise testing to see whether the bottleneck was in your serialization process?

Comment: @ChristianConkle For time, GC is 63%, CAF is 14%, Database.LevelDB is 10% Data.Serialize.Builder is 2%. Not sure who is guilty of the GC but Data.Serialize.Builder is 82% of alloc so probably that one. I'll try again just inserting ByteStrings since they don't have to go through Cereal.

Comment: @ChristianConkle Yeah. Without serializing it's 7s to insert 1M records which is respectable.